# Writing .htaccess without losing the value of my parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need some help trying to write my .htaccess

I have one single php file linked to a mysql, lets assume that my site is: www.mycustomsite.com

I am trying to avoid my page to break when someone type something like www.mycustomsite.com/personname where personname could actually be anything, and I will get this value to search on my database

people could access my site either by

1. Typing directly www.mycustomsite.com
2. Typing a directory www.mycustomsite.com/personname
3. Sometimes it will be like www.mycustomsite.com/personname?id=123&subid=123
4. www.mycustomsite.com/?id=123&subid=123

so in other words
if this is open www.mycustomsite.com/?id=123&subid=123 i should be able to get my values id and subid
and if something like this is open
www.mycustomsite.com/personname?id=123&subid=123 i need to be able to get id, subid and name = personname

I was able to do something like this, but it is not passing the rest of my parameters

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?name=%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation. The required `QSA` flag is clearly described in there, also _why_ it is required. You cannot really use apache modules without reading the documentations. Just copying form examples is nice, but not sufficient to really get going. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a `QSA` flag and a condition to stop rewriting for real files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?name=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.